# post csv file directly from pandas data frame (pandas_to.csv)

Tags: python, pandas, curl, request

I'm looking for a way to post a csv file **directly** from a pandas data frame without the need of saving it in a local file, and then posting it.

In my case, the URL is a service listening to my request that requires a scv

Is there a way to have a url as an argument into a df.to_csv(url) that will post it directly?

I tried the following: (got bad response )

```
import requests
agg_data=pd.read_csv('some_csv.csv')
r = requests.post('http://crystal-ball-some_url', data ={'agg_data':agg_data.to_csv()})
print (r)
<Response [400]>
```

Comment: Post it where? HTTP post? Csv is a string already so just send it? .post(df.to_csv(index=False))

Comment: @AntonvBR thanks for the help, see my edit

Comment: did you try to add the target URL string pd.to_csv(URL) instead of a filename, as if you would do when saving it to local file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Anton vBR thanks!

This turned out to work:

```
slider_output = agg_data.to_csv()
        files = {'file': ('agg_data.csv', slider_output)}
        requests.post('some_url', files=files)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @AntonvBR. Below code worked for me with python 3.7.3

```
import requests
files = {('files', ('aug_template.csv', aug_annotation_df.to_csv()))}
response = requests.post(url=UPLOAD_URL, params=params, files=files, data=body)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When answering to an old question (this one is over 2 years old) that already has an accepted answer (that is the case here) make sure your answer adds something substantially new. Don't answer if not.